# Wordpress theme deleting pieces of PHP causes blank screen

Tags: php, wordpress, zurb-foundation

I am trying to modify a child theme based on wp-foundation and I'm trying to edit the front page.

This is the front page code in the main theme;

```
    <?php
/*
Template Name: Homepage
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

            <div id="content">

                <div id="main" class="twelve columns" role="main">

                    <article role="article">

                        <?php

                        $orbit_slider = of_get_option('orbit_slider');
                        if ($orbit_slider){

                        ?>

                        <header>

                            <div id="featured">

                            </div>

                        </header>


                        <?php } ?>

                        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                        <section class="row post_content">

                            <div class="home-main eight columns">

                                <?php the_content(); ?>

                            </div>


                        </section> <!-- end article header -->

                        <footer>

                            <p class="clearfix"><?php the_tags('<span class="tags">Tags: ', ', ', '</span>'); ?></p>

                        </footer> <!-- end article footer -->

                    </article> <!-- end article -->

                    <?php 
                        // No comments on homepage
                        //comments_template();
                    ?>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>  



                    </article>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                </div> <!-- end #main -->


            </div> <!-- end #content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Whenever I try to delete some code (I want to get rid of the built in orbit slider and use a plugin for example) but when I delete this piece;

```
<?php
$orbit_slider = of_get_option('orbit_slider');
                        if ($orbit_slider){

                        ?>
```

The page just goes blank. I thought I was doing this in a 'clean' way, though I am not so familiar with PHP so I don't get why the page goes blank. I want to delete more of the php codes (basically I want a clean empty page to start with.) but they all give the same result; a blank page.

Why can't I just remove these pieces, why does this error occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you have removed `if ($orbit_slider){`, but you have left the closing curly brace  `<?php } ?>`

Remove that line just after the header closing tag.

```
</header>


      remove this ---->  <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your wp-config.php  look for

`define('WP_DEBUG', false);`

and replace it with

`define('WP_DEBUG', true);`

which will show errors instead of blank screen (only for development)
 for this piece of code you are getting error because

`if ($orbit_slider){`

starts an if loop. try removing only

`$orbit_slider = of_get_option('orbit_slider');`

Comment: Thank you for the comment on the debug thing, that is really useful! Leaving the if loop resulted in another error though. The answer below (removing the closing tag) solved the problem.

Comment: that's certainly not the right way to do because code inside the if loop is still executing ..if ($orbit_slider){

                        ?>

                        <header>

                            <div id="featured">

                            </div>

                        </header>


                        <?php } ?> you must remove this whole section of code to avoid designing issues